# Server crashed a few times due to lack of memory - how can I find out how much is available to each process?

Tags: apache2, mysql, ram

We had a huge spike in traffic with lots of these errors:

```
Feb 17 10:44:13 111488 kernel: [8275767.506198] Out of memory: Kill process 20577 (apache2) score 52 or sacrifice child
Feb 17 11:02:06 111488 kernel: [8276839.559141] Out of memory: Kill process 20719 (mysqld) score 75 or sacrifice child
```

As you can see, it's not just one process but both apache2 and mysqld, so I've increased the RAM on the server. How can I check that this is available to these processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [top] command

```
top - 15:20:30 up  6:57,  5 users,  load average: 0.64, 0.44, 0.33
Tasks: 265 total,   1 running, 263 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.8 us,  2.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.9 id,  0.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8167848 total,  6642360 used,  1525488 free,  1026876 buffers
KiB Swap:  1998844 total,        0 used,  1998844 free,  2138148 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                 
 2986 enlighte  20   0  584m  42m  26m S  14.3  0.5   0:44.27 yakuake                                                                                 
 1305 root      20   0  448m  68m  39m S   5.0  0.9   3:33.98 Xorg                                                                                    
 7701 enlighte  20   0  424m  17m  10m S   4.0  0.2   0:00.12 kio_thumbnail
```

or [htop] command,

[image: htop result]

Source: [BinaryTides](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/)

Comment: Brilliant. That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To get an overview of the memory use of your system, use the command `free`. For memory calculations *per process*, cf. [How can I display the memory usage of each process](https://superuser.com/questions/102005/how-can-i-display-the-memory-usage-of-each-process-if-i-do-a-ps-ef).